# Nondimensionalization of an ODE with an extra parameter

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, dimensional-analysis

I have the following coupled ODEs, which describe a system of inter-specific interactions within an ecosystem:

$$\frac{dx}{dt} = rx\left(1 - \frac{x}{K}\right) -bxy$$

$$\frac{dx}{dt}= -cy + dxy$$

with $ b,c,d,r$ and $K$ are positive constants. I have already provided a nondimensionalized system with a change in variables in the following fashion:

$$ u =\frac{x}{K},  v =\frac{b}{r}y,  \tau=rt $$

And a change of parameters like the following:

$$ \alpha = \frac{c}{r}, \beta = \frac{dK}{r} $$

so that I end up with the following nondimensionalized system:

$$ \frac{du}{d\tau}= u(1 - u - v) $$

$$ \frac{dv}{d\tau}= v(- \alpha + \beta u) $$

My problem is that now I want to nondimendionalize the followint system, which is the same except for the inclusion of an extra parameter, $a > 0$, in the first ODE:

$$\frac{dx}{dt} = rx(x - a)\left(1 - \frac{x}{K}\right) -bxy$$

$$\frac{dx}{dt}= -cy + dxy$$

I'm getting really stuck when I try to provide a nondimensionalization of the system. ¿Any hints on how to handle that $(x-a)$ ?

Comment: Define clean non-dimensionalisation?

Comment: I was refering to the simplest (less-parameterized) non-dimensionalisation, have no experience with these sort of things.